# Creating a shortcode for a Custom Post Type wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I've read a few questions on this topic, but none are quite what I'm after.

I'm trying to create a shortcode for a Custom Post Type I've created. I'd like to display one Post Type at a time which the user can select by category in the shortcode.

e.g. [feature-diagram category_name="snake"]

Here's the code I have so far. I'm able to print the ID and Title of the correct post, but I can't see any of the Custom Fields I've added for the post type (i.e. repeaters, feature_description etc).

Here is my code.. am I missing something?

```
add_shortcode( 'feature-diagram' , 'feature_diagrams_function');

function feature_diagrams_function( $atts ) {
ob_start();

extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'type' => 'feature_diagrams',
    'category' => '',
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    ), $atts ) );

$options = array (
    'type' => $type,
    'category_name' => $category,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $options );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="feature-image">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="f1">
            <p><?php the_ID(); ?></p>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <?php

            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
            if( have_rows('features_left') ):
                ?><p>Has rows</p><?php

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('features_left') ) : the_row();
                    ?>

                    <div class="feature left" id="feature-<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">
                        <div class="icon"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('feature_icon'); ?>"></div>
                        <div class="feature-text">
                            <div class="title" ><?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?></div>
                            <div class="description"><?php the_sub_field('feature_description'); ?></div>
                            <div class="middle-image"><?php the_sub_field('middle_feature_image'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php 
                endwhile;
            else :
                // no rows found
            endif;

            ?>


        </div><!-- f1 --> 

        <div class="f1">
        </div><!-- f1 --> 

        <div class="f1">
            <?php

            // check if the repeater field has rows of data
            if( have_rows('features_right') ):

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('features_right') ) : the_row();
                    ?>

                    <div class="feature right"  id="feature-<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">
                        <div class="icon"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('feature_icon'); ?>"></div>
                        <div class="feature-text">
                            <div class="title"><?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?></div>
                            <div class="description"><?php the_sub_field('feature_description'); ?></div>
                            <div class="middle-image"><?php the_sub_field('middle_feature_image'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php 
                endwhile;
            else :
                // no rows found
            endif;

            ?>


    </div><!-- f1 --> 
</div><!-- flex --> 
</div><!-- Featured Image -->
<?php
    $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
}
}
```

Comment: Try changing `if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>` to `if ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>` Running `the_post()` on the query will set up the global `$post` variable, which is used by [`have_rows()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/)